# Socket.io-client cannot connect to server using websocket transport

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a socket.io Server in Node.js. To test it, I am developing a set of integration tests using Jest. Each test establishes a connection to my local Socket.io Server, however, I am unable to require that the transport is 'websocket'.

I know that my Socket.io Server supports the websocket transport, as it I demonstrate when the browser connects to it.

Is there anything different about running the socket.io Client in Node.js that prevents the 'websocket' transport from being used?